# AWS Route 53 Domain not working on my wifi but okay on LTE

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Route 53 Issue? server DNS address could not be found.

Everything was working fine until this morning. I bought  from amazon a few weeks back and had deployed a personal webpage, no issues. Today, I made a small change and added a favicon to the page. Then I redeployed, everything is working. http://34.211.101.154/

Now I'm having issues with route 53. I've checked and double checked my name servers (ns) to make sure that the registered ns match the hosted ns. I have a health check running and it shows that all the endpoints terminate with a success 200.

```
Success: HTTP Status Code 200, OK. Resolved IP: 34.211.101.154
```

But still, when i go to the domain name, the request won't resolve on wifi but it is okay on LTE. Does anybody know the issue? Please help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the dig output while on wifi.  On macOS or Linux, run "dig domain.com" (replace with your domain) and provide the output.

Comment: is your wifi able to resolve other URLs let say google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, turns out everything was working fine. It's just AWS needed time to process the request... I waited like 2 hours and it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the wifi router you're using has cached some DNS configuration. Try resetting the router or using a different wifi network to test the issue.